# Redirect/capture stdout without the program knowing it

Tags: c#, process, stdout, io-redirection

I am using a third-party command line tool which writes its output to the console, but, unfortunately, **does not write when it detects stdout is redirected**.  I need to write a c# application that captures the output, but that can't work using the usual methods because redirecting to my app turns off the output.

Is there a way to redirect stdout/stderr *without the program knowing* it is redirected?

Comment: We'll need to know more about this third party tool.  If it's a .net program I'd look into spoofing [this property here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It is not a .net program.  I believe it is written in either c++ or (sigh) fortran.

Comment: It knows.  _isatty() is all knowing.  They figured out a long time ago that flushing the stdout buffer is only necessary for human eyes.  Inspiring David Cutler's dismissal of Unix operating systems: "getta byte, getta byte, getta byte byte byte".  Sing it to the William Tell overture.